# multiple threads using Cuda with pytorch yields lower utilization per process

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I tried to use pytorch.cuda in my application. They just send model and data to gpu using the following, then do some training.

```
    //some steps connecting to middleware and
    //let the middleware actually call cuda and execute from there
    model = model.cuda()
    normed_train_data = normed_train_data.cuda()
```

Then I run it twice from command line:

```
python xxxx.py&
python xxxx.py&python xxxx.py&
```

The first trial gives 40% utilization of GPU,but the second gives 65%. Also I found they are running in parallel, so each only use 32.5% roughly. Why does this happen? Also, is it because the actually cuda calling is from my middleware, these 2 processes somehow share the same context in different streams so that they run in parallel? But I'm confused with lower utilization.
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: The bottleneck can be I/O or data preprocessing. How is your CPU utilization rate in two scenarios?

Comment: They are 50% and 60% respectively,(with some other progs running), and I don't think I/O is the cause because it's measured in the phase of calculation.